# Why can't my users find my ClickOnce application's exe?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, clickonce

I have an app and my users need to right click on files they create > Open With > Choose Programs > MyApp.exe - but they can't because they cannot find it on their system. All they can find is a bunch of useless Shortcut files that open the program. But these shortcuts are completely useless.

I have handled the args to open files from explorer in my app (Program.cs etc) and have setup and signed manifest/certfile but they still cannot set my app as default app for specified file(s) or open files with my app from explorer. How do we get this to work with Clickonce apps? I've read the docs, and they haven't helped.

Answer (score 1):

This feature has been introduced as of Framework 3.5
This is how you do it:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mwade/archive/2008/01/30/how-to-add-file-associations-to-a-clickonce-application.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I had similar request on a project I was working on. ClickOnce apps are installed in a user profile vs Program Files folder. My alternative was using a different file extension for my "custom" files.

[How to: Create File Associations For a ClickOnce Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb892924.aspx)

Hope that helps.